# Open Wrt with nodogsplash

Tags: ssh, openwrt, router, wifi-hotspot, opkg

I am using OpenWrt in my TP_Link TL-WRD3600 router. I have already set up a hotspot plugin (Nodogsplash) on my router. Now I need to allow access to some website before authentication on the splash page.

But I need to allow this website using its domain name, eg: `example.com`, because my splash page logs in to an external website.

```
FirewallRuleSet preauthenticated-users {

     FirewallRule allow tcp port 80 to example.com

}
```

But clients are not allowed to navigate to this page before authentication has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best bet would be to use a transparent proxy by default to allow access to the login URL of your authentication website and none other.

After they have authenticated you could selectively remove them from the transpareny proxy rules in your firewall table.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.tinyproxy might fit the bill, though I have not used it myself yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer. Could you please explain how to do this with transperent proxy.

Comment: Is possible to set DNS name in Nodogsplash ?